# unknown c++ syntax in leetcode submissions

Tags: c++, lambda, syntax, io, std

I have been seeing code like this in submissions at leetcode.com and I don't understand it. My unfamiliarity with the syntax has made it hard to search for an explanation.

```
static const int _ = []() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}()
```

I gather that the I/O calls are an effort to increase execution speed. What I am not grasping is the syntax- is this a function definition, or a lambda expression? How is this code ever executed?

Comment: It's a _Lambda expression_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda the last `()` is the call to execute it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: That's a very good link I'll be studying. What's missing for me is the reminder that this code will have to be executed to initialize the static const int variable.

Comment: "_...All non-local variables with static storage duration are initialized as part of program startup, before the execution of the main function ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is lambda syntax, so what they're doing is creating a c++ lambda which performs the code above and evaluates it, then stores the result as a `static const int`. More information here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

My best guess is that this function will be evaluated first before `main` is called as `static const` values are initialized prior to starting the program. It seems like a hacky version of a state initializer for stdio.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks! 

I wonder why they've all chosen to use the underscore for the variable name.

Comment: It's traditionally used in C/Python to signify that the variable isn't important or is never used. Hope this helps!